# Galleria slider from left—right to top—bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, galleria

I'm tryin to implement the galleria.js (slideshow) on my website.
All I want is to have the slides entering from the top of the screen and going out from the bottom, instead of the classic right—left.

I've tried to rotate the images 90% and it kinds of work but I'm sure there's an easier more correct way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The isn't any way to do it through the options. here are a [list of configurables from the galleria.js site](http://galleria.io/docs/options/#list-of-options)

The only way would be to use `extend` and create a plugin to do what you need:

```
Galleria.run('.galleria', {
    extend: function() {
        // Custom code/functionality goes here
    }
});
```

You can then distribute this to anyone else who needs the same functionality.